# Delete folders with specified folder names old than certain days old

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete some folders with special name format yyyy-mm-dd only using following code but it does not work. Please help to rectify.

```
FORFILES /p “d:\testing” /S /m *-*-* /D -10 /C “cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path”
```

[image: error]

Comment: The command goes by the age of the folder no matter what the name of the folder says....

Comment: You have the wrong kind of quotes (smart quotes). Replace them with `"`